# How to Stop/Remove all DispatcherTimers in the Dispatcher's internal List<DispatcherTimer>?

Tags: c#, dispatcher, dispatchertimer

The `Dispatcher` class maintains an internal `List<DispatcherTimer>` for active timers. The internal `Dispatcher.AddTimer()` method adds it, called on the `Start()` method. `RemoveTimer()` is called by the `Stop()` method.

I need to clear that internal `List<DispatcherTimer>`. Is it possible to Stop/Remove all timers in the `Dispatcher`?

Comment: Why do not call `Stop()` for all timers? What are you trying to do ([X problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/299295))?

Comment: Basically I register some DispatcherTimers for notifications every minute (inside another Timer) and I dont want them to be fired more than once. Therefore I need to clear them every minute, before I register new ones.
Is it at least a bit clear?

Comment: And of course I call Stop() for all of them, but I need to Stop some of them before they are fired.

Comment: You describe *how you do* something (using `DispatcherTimer`), but you didn't answer what problem you are trying to solve. Why do you need to stop timers? Maybe using timer is not a good idea? Maybe a simple cancelable `Task` will do?